# Can you Move an Annotaion Layer to a different Annotation Data-Block

Tags: interface, workflow, linked-data, annotation

I want to know if there is a way to Move an annotation layer from one Annotation data-block to another

- Move this Annotation Layer

[image]

- In This Annotation Layer

[image]

- To this annotation layer

[image]

Thankyou For your help and advice

Comment: Can't even seem to find an option when looking through the blender file viewer in the outliner... as far as I can tell this just ain't possible for some reason, but I'd love to be proven wrong.

Comment: @NascentSpace  Even i'd love it if there was a way to do this :). thankyou for your help

Comment: if you go to the blend file, you will find them under "Grease Pencil (legacy)". With script you can access them, e.g. `bpy.data.grease_pencils["Building"].layers["Building Drawings 3"].info`. Now one needs to figure out how to copy them between the block.

Comment: Thankyou So Much @Blunder I'll try that out. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a complete script that copies one annotation to a different layer and/or to a different sketchbook. It copies the strokes of annotation and adds them to the choosen destination layer.

Just to clarify the terminology:

- annotations are *Grease Pencil* objects in a sketchbook **(1)** that can have multiply layers **(2)**. In the blend file, you will find them under "Grease Pencil (legacy)" **(3)**. [image: annotation sketchbook]
- the layers are the entries that you see in the viewport's sidepanel (<kbd>N</kbd>):
  [image: annotation layers]
- annotations are bound to the frames of the timeline. They appear after the certain frame **(4)**:
  [image: annotations in the side panel]

To run the script, create a new text data block, paste the code, change the source and destination values, and run it with the play button (top right corner).

```
import bpy

print("Copying annotations ...")

src_sketchbook = 'Annotations'
dest_sketchbook = 'Annotations'
src_anno_name =  'Note'
dest_anno_name = 'Note.001'

src_anno = bpy.data.grease_pencils[src_sketchbook].layers[src_anno_name]
dest_anno = bpy.data.grease_pencils[dest_sketchbook].layers[dest_anno_name]

src_frame = src_anno.active_frame
if src_frame is None:
    if len(src_anno.frames) > 0:
        src_frame = src_anno.frames[0]
    else:
        raise Exception(f"Annotation has no frame data. No frame to copy in annotaion {src_anno_name}!") 

src_strokes = src_frame.strokes        # is a collection of GPencilStroke objects

# find the dest frame with the same number as the src frame has
dest_frame = None
for df in dest_anno.frames:
    if df.frame_number == src_frame.frame_number:
        dest_frame = df

# create a frame for destination annotation if we don't have found one
if dest_frame == None:
    frame_no = src_frame.frame_number
    print(f"destination annotation's frame is None, creating a new frame at frame {frame_no}")
    dest_frame = dest_anno.frames.new(frame_no)
    print("new GPencilFrame object created")
dest_strokes = dest_frame.strokes

# copy strokes and their points from src to dest
for ss in src_strokes:
    ds = dest_strokes.new()                    # new dest stroke
    ds.points.add(len(ss.points))              # ... with same amount of points

    # copy the point data
    for idx, src_point in enumerate(ss.points):
        dest_point = ds.points[idx]            
        dest_point.co.x = src_point.co.x       # copy stroke coordinates
        dest_point.co.y = src_point.co.y
        dest_point.co.z = src_point.co.z
        dest_point.pressure = src_point.pressure  # tablet data? 
        dest_point.strength = src_point.strength

print("Done.")
```